# ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here when adding case when

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case-when

I have a piece of code which runs fine. However, when i am introducing a "case when" statement in the select clause, I get the "group function is not allowed here" error and I cannot fix it (the issue relates to the last Group by function in my code)

Any idea why (don't be put off by the code, it is 3 joins together, apparently the issue is caused by the last Group By statement) ?

Thank you!

```
SELECT 
  Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO
  , (case when Cash. MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table. MTAGRE01_NO
     then (SUM(Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU)*-1)
     else   SUM(Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU) END)        AS MTTRANS01_VALUENCU

FROM MTTRANS01 Trans_Table
INNER JOIN  RUTRANTYPE01 Trans_Type
ON  Trans_Type.RUTRANTYPE01_CODE  = Trans_Table.RUTRANTYPE01_CODE

LEFT JOIN(
SELECT 
  MTAGRE01_NO
 ,CASE WHEN SRAGRESTAT01_CODE = 'COLL' THEN MTAGRE01_AGRESTATDATE END AS Date_Fr
 from MTAGRE01
 where CASE WHEN SRAGRESTAT01_CODE = 'COLL' THEN MTAGRE01_AGRESTATDATE END  is not null
) F_Date 
ON  F_Date.MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO

LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
      Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO
FROM MTTRANS01 Trans_Table
INNER JOIN  RUTRANTYPE01 Trans_Type  ON  Trans_Type.RUTRANTYPE01_CODE  = Trans_Table.RUTRANTYPE01_CODE
GROUP BY
  Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO, Trans_Type.RUTRANTYPE01_CODE, Trans_Type.RUTRANTYPE01_DESCRIPTION
) Cash
ON Cash.MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO

where Trans_Type.SRPROCTYPE01_CODE in ('C','D') 
and Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUEDATE >=  F_Date.Date_Fr

GROUP BY
  Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO
, (case when Cash. MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table. MTAGRE01_NO
        then (SUM(Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU)*-1)
        else   SUM(Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU) END);
```

Comment: Your group by statement in the cash statement is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's hung up on the sum inside the case statement.  2 routes to correct that I can see, likely alot more:

This is a little hacky, but it'll work and give results fast.  Change your case:

```
SELECT 
Trans_Table.MTAGRE01_NO
, (case when Cash. MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table. MTAGRE01_NO
 then ((Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU)*-1)
 else   (Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU) END)        AS MTTRANS01_VALUENCU
```

Remove the case from the group by.

Now call your entire query a sub query

```
Select MTAGRE01_NO, sum(MTTRANS01_VALUENCU)
(your entire query)a
```

You other option that takes a bit more work...in your initial from statement:

```
MTTRANS01 Trans_Table
```

Change that to a subquery that joins to the trans table and returns

```
case when Cash. MTAGRE01_NO = Trans_Table. MTAGRE01_NO
 then ((Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU)*-1)
 else   (Trans_Table.MTTRANS01_VALUENCU) END as MTAGRE01_NO

Then join to that subquery and do a simple sum in your main query.
```

Hopefully that all makes sense, ask questions if you need clarifications